# Retrieve value from object PHP

Tags: php, object

so currently I have a script where running

```
$obj = $this->search()->browse()->params($aBrowseParams);
```

returns the following data to $obj

```
Phpfox_Search_Browse Object
(
    [_iCnt:Phpfox_Search_Browse:private] =&gt; 2


    [_aParams:Phpfox_Search_Browse:private] =&gt; Array
        (
            [module_id] =&gt; music.song
            [alias] =&gt; m
            [field] =&gt; song_id
            [table] =&gt; phpfox_music_song
            [hide_view] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; pending
                    [1] =&gt; my
                )

            [service] =&gt; music.song.browse
        )

    [_oBrowse:Phpfox_Search_Browse:private] =&gt; Music_Service_Song_Browse Object
        (
            [_sTable:protected] =&gt; 
        )

    [_sView:Phpfox_Search_Browse:private] =&gt; 
    [_aConditions] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; AND ( (m.title LIKE '%test%') )
            [1] =&gt; AND m.view_id = 0 AND m.privacy IN(0)
            [2] =&gt; AND m.item_id = 0
        )

)
```

I'm attempting to get the following value

```
AND ( (m.title LIKE '%test%') )
```

Now I've tried converting it to an array using

```
$arr= (array) $obj;
```

then simply getting the value by specifying

```
$obj['value']['value']
```

but it's not working, how should I retrieve the value?

Comment: I think there should be methods for accessing properties of object in phpFox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

`$value = $obj->_aConditions[0];`

This should work as long as `_aConditions` is a public array in the object.

Comment: Terrible naming if `_aConditions` is public. Generally anything that starts with `_` should be private/protected.

Comment: It looks like it may be public judging by the output he posted.

Comment: Oh, I agree. In the object above it *is* public. I just meant in general methods/properties that start with an underscore are not public.

Comment: `aConditions` is indeed public, infact it is not even declared as a property. http://phpwolfcamp.com/phpFoxDocuments/html/include_2library_2phpfox_2search_2browse_8class_8php_source.html

Comment: That would be inaccessible without some kind of method to get it for you... i.e. `$conditions = $obj->getConditions()`

Comment: Reading the docs @MrCode linked, there is a getConditions() method on the object returned by search() method. That may be more future safe if phpFox ever fixes that _aConditions not private thing.
`$conditions = $this->search()->getConditions();`

Comment: I saw that aswell although it did quite a few other things aswell, I ended up creating a new function in e same file getConditions is located with simple 

`public function getTerm()
 {
  return $this->_aSearch;
 }`